# class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

At first, I want to say that there are other topic with this problem but I tried the solutions and it didn't work for me.

I explain my problem. I begin to developp a Javafx project with Maven on my computer. In this computer the SDK java is 10.

Now I must to develop on another computer. I take my source with Git and open it with Intellij. But when I tried to run my application, it crash with this message:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x45b904e9) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x45b904e9
```

I tried many things but nothing works. I don't understand. It seems like the program don't access to javafx things that it needs. But my Maven import javafx. My Maven file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjetER-Scan</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>12</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13-ea+3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13-ea+3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13-ea+3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: IntelliJ won't add the dependencies to the module-path. You can add the `javafx-maven-plugin`, as explained here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij sections Non-modular or Modular with Maven.

Comment: In this case, why my code worked with java 10 ? I'll try that and I say you if it works.

Comment: Because JDK 10 includes JavaFX, while JDK 11 doesn’t

Comment: Hello i resolved the problem with the documentation that you send. Thanks, I build a new project Maven with the right artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same ussue and i just fix it. I added `--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` to configuration, i read about it [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij) (watch Add VM options)

Comment: ```
 --module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "
```
[here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij)